# GET Dynamic Date file using SFTP?

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp

I am creating a bash file which will download file daily but file name is dynamic it generates file on the basis of date something like **'20190819.log'** My code is as follows :

```
   export SSHPASS=$SFTP_PASS
   DATE=`$DATE -d "-1 day" +"%Y%m%d"`

   sshpass -e sftp -oBatchMode=no -b - $SFTP_USER@$SFTP_HOST<<-'EOF'
    mget $DATE.log
   EOF
```

But in line **mget $DATE.log** it is treating $DATE as string. 
Need help...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't quote `'EOF'`. The quotes tell bash not to expand parameters inside the here-doc

Comment: @rici so what should I add in stead of EOF in order to make it functional ?

Comment: EOF is fine. Just lose the quotes.

Comment: @rici great It worked you can add answer so that I can accept it...Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

When you put quotes around the here-doc end delimiter (`<<-'EOF'` in this case), you are asking the shell to *not* expand parameters in the here-doc. If you want shell variables to be expanded, lose the quotes (`<<-EOF`).

But in this particular case, you might find that [`scp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html) is easier to use.